# How to access java class from another application?

Tags: java

I have a java package with classes  in netbeans.I need to import those package for another java application in netbeans.but the classes in package is not have main method.how do i import those classes?

Comment: why do you need a main method to import?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `import` in your current class. Those classes in the other package need not have main methods in them.

**E.g:-** `import package2.subpackage.ClassNameToBeImported;`

Answer (score 0):

You have not required main class for import the package.

I give one example.

> import package.classname;

Now, you can create the Object of this class and the call the method using this object.

You don't require the main class.
You try it, Say me what happen.

Answer (score 0):

use import keyword to import the package.

And also make sure that the jar file or the directory containing the class files of project that define those packages are included in the classpath of the project that use them.

Answer (score 0):

You want to import those classes in another application/project and you use netbeans : 
One way :
1. while creating new application/project you can choose "**create project from existing resources**".
2. select the packages where they are stored(mostly in my document folder)

you will see those packages available in your new application.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a jar of those classes and import / add the jar in the other application.

Comment: how to convert java class library into jar?..Actually,I have created a java class library namely "Procedurelibrary".In that i have package namely "DB_Class".I have two class inside this package namely "call_procedure" and "db_connection". Now my problem is,When i try to access those package from another application,It will not recognized by netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need main method here.just use import statement then invoke respective methods.
The main method need only in the case of to run single class.